# Joins in Grails Criteria

Tags: grails, grails-orm, grails-domain-class

I'm trying to write a criteria query in grails, for the following domains:

```
class Data {
    Long createdById // this is user id
    // other fields
}
class User {
   Company company
   // other fields
}
```

Now data, as the name suggest stores some data. It is not directly related to User but has a field createdById which is the id of User. 
(I cannot give direct reference of User in Data because these belongs to different projects, where Data is from a custom reusable plugin.)

Now I want to write criteria on Data and list all records where it was created by users of a given company. that is `data.id == User.id and user.company == givenCompany`

Comment: I think you're going to have to link the two GORM objects with a relationship on order to do that with a criteria.  A join requires you to define the one-to-one or one-to-many relationships between the objects (https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/guide/GORM.html#manyToOneAndOneToOne)  Once you define that, you can create the criteria on one or the other of the objects.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to use any GORM/Hibernate query method (criteria, where, or HQL) you need an association between the domain classes. Since you can't make an association from `Data` to `User`, you cannot use GORM to write your query with your domain classes are they are. In other words, you need to use SQL; HQL (`DomainClass.executeQuery()` will not work). But...

### With HQL

If you're willing to modify `User` and maintain some redundant data, you can use HQL.

```
class User {
   Company company
   // other fields

   /* Add uni-directional one-to-many */
   static hasMany = [data: Data]
}

def data = AnyDomainClass.executeQuery('SELECT d FROM User as u INNER JOIN u.data AS d WHERE u.company = :company', [company: givenCompany])
```

The uni-directional one-to-many association creates a join table which would need to be maintained to reflect `Data.createdById`. The HQL join syntax hints at the fact that associations are required. If you must use a criteria query...

### With criteria query

To use a criteria query you'll need to modify `User` and add an additional domain class. The reason is that a criteria query cannot *project* an association like HQL can. For example, this will **not** work:

```
def data = User.withCriteria {
    eq('company', givenCompany)

    projections {
        property('data')
    }
}
```

Due to not being able to modify `Data`, this --which is the simplest solution-- will also **not** work:

```
def data = Data.withCriteria {
    user {
        eq('company', givenCompany)
    }
}
```

So, you need a middle-man in order to project `Data` instances:

```
class User {
   Company company
   // other fields

   static hasMany = [userData: UserData]
}

class UserData {
    Data data

    static belongsTo = [user: User]
}

def data = User.withCriteria {
    eq('company', givenCompany)

    projections {
        userData {
            property('data')
        }
    }
}
```

As you can imagine, this method also requires some data maintenance.

### Using SQL

Lastly, you have the option of using SQL and having the query return domain class instances. It boils down to something like this:

```
AnyDomainClass.withNewSession { session ->
    def data = session.createSQLQuery('SQL GOES HERE').addEntity(Data).list()
}
```

### More info

For more information, check out my following articles:

1. [Domain class associations and how they work on the DB level](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/grails-domain-class-associations/)
2. [Joining domain classes with GORM queries](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/gorm-for-sqladdicts-from-clause/)
3. [Using SQL and returning domain class instances](http://emmanuelrosa.com/articles/running-sql-queries-from-grails/). *Available on Jan 22nd.*

Answer (score 1):

If you are able to create sql query for this and not able to create criteria for this then you can look for [executeQuery](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/3.0.x/ref/Domain%20Classes/executeQuery.html)

I hope it should work

Comment: thanks for the answer, yes I have already written a query for it to serve the purpose, but there should be a way to do this with grails criteria as well.. and I would like to learn and use that.